# NSMutableDictionary: Cast to unrelated Swift type?

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting, nsmutabledictionary

Can anyone help me out with the correct way round this, I have tried various versions but always hit either an error or a warning. The code and output below are from a Swift Playground.

```
var foundationDict = NSMutableDictionary()
foundationDict.setObject("Bilbo", forKey: "FirstName")
foundationDict.setObject("Baggins", forKey: "LastName")

var swiftDict = foundationDict as! Dictionary<String, String>
for (key, value) in swiftDict {
    print("KEY: \(key) VALUE: |\(value)")
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
KEY: FirstName VALUE: |Bilbo
KEY: LastName VALUE: |Baggins
```

WARNING:

```
Cast from NSMutableDictionary to unrelated type Dictionary<String String> always fails
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why, but phrasing it this way silences the warning:

```
var swiftDict = (foundationDict as NSDictionary) as! Dictionary<String, String>
```

The type system seems to struggle with NSMutableDictionary/NSDictionary in this case.

Comment: I noticed the same after casting foundationDict to NSDictionary too. It just seems a little odd as swiftDict is mutable anyways. Thanks for taking a look, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A correct version of your code is:

```
var foundationDict = NSMutableDictionary()
foundationDict.setObject("Bilbo", forKey: "FirstName")
foundationDict.setObject("Baggins", forKey: "LastName")

for (key, value) in foundationDict {
   println("KEY: \(key) VALUE: |\(value)")
}
```

There is no need in casting because NSDictionary is bridged to swift Dictionary and foundationDict is now a swift mutableDict.

Comment: My intention for casting to Swift was that I have  a lot of other functions that take the dictionary as an argument. I wanted all these to be Swift native so that if Apple in the future decide to extend Dictionary to cover the functionality of NSDictionary I would not have to change anything down stream.

Comment: Swift bridging will take care, don't worry.

Comment: I will give it a go and see how I get on, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

without warning you can follow this way

```swift
var addressDict = NSMutableDictionary()
addressDict["key"] = "value"

if let dict = (addressDict as NSDictionary) as? [String:AnyObject]  {
    print(dict) 
}
```